# Send file with telegram api

Tags: c#, api, url, telegram, telegram-bot

I use the following link to send the file

https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendDocument?chat_id=&document=**https://photo06b010.jpg**

But I want to use the path of the file on the hard drive instead of the link in the document section

Like
https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendDocument?chat_id=&document=**C:\Users\photo06b010.jpg**

I searched a lot but did not find a way

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible.

In the [Telegram API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputfile) you will find a descritption of currently available ways to send a file.